# Can't remove eventListener

Tags: javascript

I have a function that listens for scrolling, but I need to invoke it several times. And this causes event listeners stacking. So I tried to remove one before adding, like this:

```
  watchButton() {
    console.log('watching button');
    const button = document.getElementById('load-more-news');
    const fetcher = () => {
      let windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight / 2;
      let offset = button.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if (offset <= windowHeight) {
        button.click();
      }
    };

    window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttle(fetcher, CONFIG.THROTTLE), true);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(fetcher, CONFIG.THROTTLE), true);
  }
```

I also tried binding `throttle` function to other variable:

```
const fetcher = () => {
  let windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight / 2;
  let offset = button.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (offset <= windowHeight) {
    button.click();
  }
};

const boundFetcher = throttle(fetcher, CONFIG.THROTTLE);

window.removeEventListener('scroll', boundFetcher, true);
window.addEventListener('scroll', boundFetcher, true);
```

But when I check event listeners tab in Chrome, I have two (and more) scroll listeners initialized here. What should I do?

Comment: You are trying to remove a different function than the one you added...so it doesn't get removed.

Comment: [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) requires the original function reference that was used with `addEventListener`, so if `throttle` isn't returning that then they won't be removed

Comment: @PatrickEvans throttle is a well-known function decorator that prevents an event handler from firing too often, its in most major js libs like underscore. And your diagnosis is accurate, it returns a new function object.

Comment: I don't understand why that was downvoted, seems like valid question. To clarify what @JaredSmith meant - you need to store result from `throttle`, call it `boundFetcher` or something like that and pass it instead

Comment: @llamerr agreed, a dv seems uncalled for here even if its an easy fix.

Comment: @llamerr I tried that (updated code in question), but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is complete code - that code is probably inside some function, but do you store that `boundFetcher` between function calls?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski, `const` when used inside a function makes that variable constant within that function call, it doesn't make it constant across multiple function calls

Comment: @TomekBuszewski removeEventListener second argument is a function not a function call

Comment: @llamerr This is a method from my component. Scrolling is done only in here.

Comment: And what do you think happens each time scrolling is triggered? this function is re-run each time and all vars, consts, etc recreated. You will have multiple different `boundFetcher`s again. You need to store it somewhere outside the function. Or just create closure which will store it.

Comment: This whole approach of _I’ll remove a specific handler, only to then add that exact same handler again_ seems rather absurd to me. Why don’t you simply set a flag, so that inside your function that you need to call multiple times you can check whether you added that handler already …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating your function reference each time `watchButton` is called, so `fetcher` and `throttle(fetcher,...)` are going to be different each time `watchButton` is called.

`const` does not make your variables constant across multiple calls to `watchButton`

Move your `const` variables outside the `watchButton` function

```
const button = document.getElementById('load-more-news');
const fetcher = () => {
  let windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight / 2;
  let offset = button.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (offset <= windowHeight) {
    button.click();
  }
};
const throttledFetch = throttle(fetcher, CONFIG.THROTTLE);

watchButton() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttledFetch, true);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', throttledFetch, true);
}
```